# How to upload CSV files over the GCP (automated process)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I have GCP server and I want to upload CSV files in an automated way.

1. I want to upload all the old CSV file (existing files) over the GCP (BigQuery Table/View)
2. I want to upload all new arriving files (each day new files arrive) - So, I want to upload only latest files.

**For now:** I am running Cloud SDK gcloud cp command manually to upload files every day. I login with Remote Desktop > Authenticate myself with GCP SDK > and run gcloud cp command to upload the files in bucket > and from bucket I loaded the data into BigQuery.

The drive is not mapped. The drive physical path is: C:\myDrive

Current solution: Server > C Drive > GCP authentication > gcloud cp command to upload the files in Bucket > Bucket to BigQuery

Looking for automation ETL Process with Dataproc or Dataflow.

Thanks and looking forward to your solutions and tutorial + steps.